# How to analyze SPFx bundle content?

Tags: javascript, spfx, gulp

I know there is webpack-bundle-size-analyzer for visualizing and analyzing bundle sizes with webpack projects but how do I integrate it (or something similar) to SPFx web part or SPFx extension project made with Yeoman generator?

Is there some gulp task example available?

Answer (score 1):

The .sppkg file packaged by the SPFx app (through `build`, `bundle` and `package-solution` gulp commands) is actually a simple archive you can unzip.

Its content can be broken down pretty easily (xml and resource files).

One thing you can also is configure a CDN in your project, so that packaging creates the .sppkg without any web resource (JS files, images and fonts) and puts them in a separate folder for you to upload to the location of your choice.

If the objective is to analyse the actual content of the compiled JS resources, I am not able to help you unfortunately.

Hope this helps!